# How to let client know what went wrong on server side?

Tags: django, error-handling

I'm new to web development and wonder what's the common practice of doing this..

For example, when a user sign up,
server might fail to sign up the user for various reasons

```
1. password doesn't match (ok.. could be validated on client side, but..)
2. email is not valid
3. email is already taken.
```

I want to keep whatever http `status code` server generated. such as 403, 500..
I just want to add the `fail code` to the response so that client can look at the fail code when status code isn't 200.

How can I do this in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you enumerated should not be server errors. They should still return a 200.

Since this is for a mobile app, I'm assuming you have an API that returns JSON or XML response.

If there's no error, your response will be like this: {"success" : True}

If there's an error, your response will be {"success" : False, "error_message" : "Email is not valid"}

Answer (score 0):

You decide which response to generate in your view. For this task is better to use django forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/# and return response with status code 200 and form with descriptions of errors.

Comment: I'm getting post-data from native mobile apps(iphone/android). I thought `form` is html, web stuff. Is django form still relavant to me?

Comment: Yes, forms are used to process POST or GET data. Then in your view you can return HttpResponse with the status code that you need and error message from the form.

Comment: Good to know. Many thanks!.  I have code like `username = request.POST['username'] ` django doc shows something like `signupForm = SignupForm(request.POST)` Do I define SignupForm with 'username' and other POST data I need and pass the request.POST to the constructor to use it?